# Why Node.js does not recognize document in document.querySelector, what can I use instead of document? I am using express

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express

I got an error for const weatherForm = document.querySelector('form')
^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object. (/Users/sheebadola/development/quadacademy/work/task-6/Webserver/src/app.js:98:21)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.14.0

I tried to move the  to the bottom of the  in HTML and still there's no fix. What can I use instead of document, how do i manipulate DOM ?

Comment: because there isn't any HTML in node.js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to manipulate DOM in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743600/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-dom-in-node-js)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `<script>` element **in an HTML document** (and open it in a browser) the entire JavaScript environment is centred about that document.

It goes *browser* ➡ *document*  ➡ *script*

The browser provides a [bunch of APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) including the `document`.

---

When you run a JS program with Node JS, there is no HTML document.

It goes *Node.js*  ➡ *script*

It isn't centred around an HTML document, so no `document` object is provided for you.

Node.js provides a different collection of APIs (mostly listed in the [table of contents for its documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html)), mostly through its built-in modules.

---

In Node.js, you could create a document object using a DOM library, but you are not running your script inside a document.

You've tagged this [express](/questions/tagged/express). When using Express it is typical to generate HTML using a [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and not with DOM manipulation.